# Create instance of classes based on some parameters

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Here's a simplified version of the problem I'm trying to solve. I have a config file where some parameters are defined for persons. As you can see there are some common attributes that are common e.g. `role` and `age` and there are some attributes that are unique to **employee** or **student**.

Example of config file:

```
role = employee
age = 38
job = teacher
salary = 1000

role = student
age = 21
course = medicine
```

I would like to read these parameters from the config file and create `Employee` or `Student` instance based on the value of the `role`.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, role, age, job, salary):
        pass

    def get_address(self):
        pass

class Student:
    def __init__(self, role, age, course):
        pass
    
    def get_address(self):
        # uses a different method for getting the address
        pass
```

The subclasses have their own implementations of some common methods e.g. `get_address()`.

The config file would be read in in a separate module, let's call it `main` for simplicity and it would then call the instance methods for each object to do various operations. The following approach looks wrong to me because `main` needs to know about every type of person supported. If I introduce a new type of person, say a `Retiree` then I would need to update main.

in `main.py`

```
if role == "employee":
    e1 = Employee(role, age, job, salary)
elif role = "student":
    s1 = Student(role, age, course)
```

Its not clear to me how I should go about creating instances of the subclasses that can be used in `main`. Looking for some guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you searching for [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)?

Comment: Also think about use a common class Person, and which is inherited by the Student and Employee classes

Comment: In your scenario, `main` *has* to know about every type of person, because it has to know what parameters are needed for that type, and in what order.

Comment: Hi! There is pattern for this kind of problem. You  can create an abstract class to group all common attribut/function and a class Factory to build your specific class from role name.

Comment: You should use inheritance.
`Student`, `Employee `share some attributes and some behavior (methods).
You can define a `Person` class with `age` and `role` attributes and the corresponding constructor, as well as a `get_address()` method.
Then you make `Student` inherit from `Person`.
`class Student(Person):
    ...`
That's for the inheritance part.
For the rest, yes you have to look at the factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'roles' are always going to have the same name as the classes, then you can look them up in the `locals` dict like this:

```
cls = locals()[role.title()]
new_person = cls(p1, p2, ...)
```

You can use the `globals` dict the same way if the classes are out of your current scope.

Comment: The class names may not always match 'roles' so this won't work. But thanks for looking.

Comment: In that case you can make a dict mapping role names to classes like: `role_dict = {'employee': Employee, ...}` and use it the same way.